# How do I rebase from upstream mercurial into a git fork?

Tags: git, github, mercurial, bitbucket, hg-git

The python library `suds` can't seem to find a [stable maintainer](https://github.com/htj/suds-htj), and the few that have picked up the slack [don't seem to agree](https://bitbucket.org/jurko/suds) on a common VCS.

There are plenty of guides on how to do various things between git and hg, however most of them seem to revolve around submodules and converting repositories back and forth. How do I simply pull in upstream changes from a remote hg branch to my local git branch? Ideally, I'd like to do the following:

```
$ git remote add upstream-jurko ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/jurko/suds
$ git pull upstream-jurko master
conq: not a git repository.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Drop Git, which doesn't have good support for external Mercurial repositories and move to Mercurial

OR

- Use [bridge in git for Mercurial and Bazaar](http://felipec.wordpress.com/2012/11/13/git-remote-hg-bzr-2/) from Felipe Contreras in your Git

Comment: I would drop one of the VCSes too.  Maintaining two VCSes takes time which you can spend on hacking your lib.  You can use http://random.org/ for solve this holy war.